# Is it possible to allow a legacy Win32 GUI app to be run from command line as well?

Tags: user-interface, winapi, cmd

We have some code that works and it's a Win32 app with a GUI, but I would like to be able to trigger it from the command line as well (silent mode). Is there any easy way to do this? Or do I have to create another project as a command line application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the application to be absolutely invisible, i.e. no window at all, you simply have to skip the part of your application that creates the main window. A normal command line application will create a console window, which will flash on the screen as the application opens and closes.

Answer (score 1):

`c:> notepad.exe`

That answer your question?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I don't want to just open the GUI app from command line. I want to be able to run the program in "silent mode" with no GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small application which start your old GUI application with respect of `CreateProcess` Windows API. `CreateProcess` has `lpStartupInfo` parameter of the type `STARTUPINFO` or `STARTUPINFOEX`. If you initialize `wShowWindow` field of this `STARTUPINFO` or `STARTUPINFOEX` to `SW_HIDE`, then the main Windows of application which will be started will be hidden. You must also set `dwFlags` of `STARTUPINFO` or `STARTUPINFOEX` which includes `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` bit mask.

Such small program starting another program in hidden mode can be also used to start a console application without opening a well known console window.